# A book about croissants/viennoiserie

Tags: french-cuisine, cookbook

I am looking for a book which concentrates on croissants. I already have some recipes and other books which either present them or delve a little bit into them.

I am looking for a more deep literature about them, about techniques, about folds, about variations in proportions and variations of ingredients.

Does such a book exist?

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually surprised that there is :

- [Celebrating Croissants: 40 Fabulous Fillings for National Croissant Day - Ideal for a Bistro Breakfast or Light Lunch](https://smile.amazon.com/Celebrating-Croissants-Fabulous-Croissant-Breakfast/dp/1984075136/)

Your other option might be to go for a more generic one on French pastries:

- [Bake Like a French Pastry Chef: Delectable Cakes, Perfect Tarts, Flaky Croissants, and More](https://smile.amazon.com/Bake-Like-French-Pastry-Chef/dp/1682681947)

I'm not familiar with either of these, but the second one reads like a text book ... glossary of terms, explanation of ingredients, step by step instructions, and lots of pictures.  (although 'Look Inside' didn't take me to the puff pastry or croissant chapters, and Amazon didn't OCR the book, so text searching won't work).  The first one Amazon doesn't have a scan of, so I have no idea how much detail it might have in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen croissant only books, but you can start with :

I found this : 
Dominique Ansel (cronuts): The Secret Recipes

Which led to : 
Baking and Pastry: Mastering the Art and Craft

Which can lead to others I'm certain, look at similar books on amazon.

I'm also certain that you could find French books like the "Le Grand Livre de la Boulangerie" (more bread than pure croissant).